# PHP function is not returning data

Tags: php, return, return-value

I have an array of data that is created by a function, but the function will not return the data.

Here is the function:

```
/**
 * Takes in a legacy id and returns new id.
 */
function my_function($data) {
  foreach ($data as $info) {
    $new_info = my_other_function($info);
    $new_data[] = $new_info;
  }

  return $new_data;
}
```

Here is where it's called:

```
$data = array('7245');
echo 'test1';                   // prints out test1
$new_data = my_function($data);
print_r($new_data);                 // DOES NOT PRINT ANYTHING, SAME RESULTS WITH VAR_DUMP()
echo 'test2';                   // prints out test2
```

However if I change the function to the following, it prints out while in the function, but still does not print out the returned value:

```
function my_function($data) {
  foreach ($data as $info) {
    $new_info = my_other_function($info);
    $new_data[] = $new_info;
  }
  print_r($new_data);
  return $new_data;
}
```

So now this:

```
$data = array('7245');
echo 'test1';                   // prints out test1
$new_data = my_function($data);
echo 'test2';                   // prints out test2
print_r($new_data);                 // DOES NOT PRINT ANYTHING, SAME RESULTS WITH VAR_DUMP()
```

Prints out this:

```
test1
array(0=>9876)
test2
// RETURNED VALUE SHOULD BE HERE BUT IT IS NOT
```

EDIT:

Since it seems this is essientally impossible, I'm adding the original function, which lives in a Drupal module.  I have test all other functions called in this function and they work perfectly on their own.

```
$file_data = '7024';
$ids = tdm_migration_import_file($file_data, $inline='no');

function tdm_migration_import_file($data, $inline) {
  // create base array
  $new_data = array();
  if (!is_array($data)) {
    $data = array($data);
  }
  // if we are reprocessing this data, remove the first element (flag) of
  // the array
  // dpm($data, 'incoming data');
  if (isset($data['reprocess'])) {
    unset($data['reprocess']);
  }
  foreach ($data as $file_data) {
    if (trim($file_data) == '') {
      continue;
    }
    // check to see if this data is coming from a text block or not
    if ($inline == 'no') {
      // given a path or fid
      if (is_numeric($file_data)) {
        // given an int (fid)
        $legacy_fid = $file_data;
        $legacy_file_path = tdm_migration_get_legacy_file_data($legacy_fid);
        // set the flag to reprocess this data
        $new_data['reprocess'] = 'yes';
        // add file path to new data for reprocessing
        $new_data[] = $legacy_file_path;
      } else {
        // given a string (path or uri/url)
        $legacy_file_path = $file_data;
        $path_data = tdm_migration_extract_path_data($legacy_file_path);
        // // if the directory doesn't exist we create it and make sure permissions
        // allow for writing by the server
        file_prepare_directory($path_data['public_path'], FILE_CREATE_DIRECTORY);
        // check to see if the file already exists in file structure
        $realpath = drupal_realpath($path_data['public_file_path']);
        if (!file_exists($realpath)) {
          // create new file and get new fid
          $fid = tdm_migration_create_file($path_data['legacy_file_url'], $path_data['public_file_path'], $data='fid');
        } else {
          // get the existing file id
          $fid = tdm_migration_get_existing_file_data($path_data['public_file_path']);
        }
        $new_data[] = $fid;
      }
    } else {
      // given a body of text, find <img> tags and extract the src attributes
      $legacy_paths = tdm_migration_extract_img_srcs($file_data);
      $replacement_paths = array();
      foreach ($legacy_paths as $legacy_path) {
        $path_data = tdm_migration_extract_path_data($legacy_path);
        file_prepare_directory($path_data['public_path'], FILE_CREATE_DIRECTORY);
        $realpath = drupal_realpath($path_data['public_file_path']);
        if (!file_exists($realpath)) {
          $new_path = tdm_migration_create_file($path_data['legacy_file_url'], $path_data['public_file_path'], $data='path');
        } else {
          $new_path = $public_file_path;
        }
        // aggregate old and new paths
        $replacement_paths[$legacy_path] = $new_path;
      }
      // replace all old paths with new paths in original text
      $new_file_data = tdm_migration_replace_text($file_data, $replacement_paths);
      $new_data[] = $new_file_data;
    }
  }
  if (isset($new_data['reprocess']) && $new_data['reprocess'] == 'yes') {
    // dpm($new_data, 'reprocessing');
    tdm_migration_import_file($new_data, $inline='no');
  } else {
    dpm($new_data, 'new-data'); // THIS PRINTS OUT!!!!!!
    return $new_data;
  }
}
```

EDIT2: There seems to be some confusion as to what this is doing so I will explain the steps in plain english.

1. $data = '7204'; The data variable is being set to a string of numbers
2. Place $data in an array, also called $data.
3. Check to see if the key 'reprocess' is set in $data, if it is, remove it
4. Itterate through the $data array, individual elements of the array now called $file_data (this function downloads files based on migration needs).
5. If the element is blank, skip it and go to the next element
6. Check if the $inline variable is set, if it is we are dealing with HTML (not the issue at hand)  In this case the data is a string of numbers.  $inline is never set to 'yes'.
7. Check to see if the element is numeric, in this case IT IS NUMERIC
8. Get the relative path, stored in the old database, using tdm_migration_get_legacy_file_data().  The new data looks something like: sites/default/files/somefile.jpg
9. Set reprocess to yes in the new_data
10. Add the returned file path to the new_data array.
11. Now the function goes to the bottom with the last if/else and checks if reprocess isset and if it is equal to yes - in this case IT IS!
12. Since reprocess is equal to yes, we run through the function again with the given string (path)!
13. UNSET reprocess!
14. Itterate through the data again
15. Not inline
16. Not numeric!  **SO REPROCESS IS NEVER SET NOW!!!**
17. Get path data (returns things like the new server path, etc) - verified working
18. Prepare the directory with write privleges and create it if it doesn't already exist
19. Check if the file already exists on the server
20. If it doesn't, then it creates the file and adds the file info to the database by running tdm_migration_create_file(), which returns the file id ($fid).  - verified working  - If it does exist, it just checks the database for the file id - verified working
21. Add the file id to $new_data.
22. Now at the bottom of the function, it goes to the **ELSE because REPROCESS IS NOT SET** and should return the data

This last part is what is wrong.  If add the line dpm($new_data, 'new-data'); before the return, it prints out exactly what it should.  For the uninitiated, dpm is a drupal fucntion that prints out data in a clean format.  If it change the dpm line to var_dump($new_data); die(); - it STILL prints the data, but the function WILL NOT RETURN IT!

Comment: In short: this is kind of impossible. Please provide a block of code which we can copy, paste and run *as is* that shows this exact problem.

Comment: Seems to work fine to me: https://eval.in/184938

Comment: @deceze - trying to find a way to do that now...this is in a drupal module and is connecting to two databases to retrieve data...there is no short way for me to explain it, so i will work on it and update the question.

Comment: Try `var_dump()` instead of `print_r()`. It should print `NULL` if it's actually not putting anything in there.

Comment: @Samsquanch - the actual function i'm using to print is dpm() which is a drupal function, but I figured i would put print_r here for those that don't know Drupal.  Same results with var_dump()

Comment: You need to provide the function my_other_function, as it's the result of that, which is ultimately output by your print_r.

Comment: Ah, I believe `dpm()` also prints `NULL` when empty, so it would serve the same purpose there.

Comment: @Bryan - by printing the variable in the my_function before the return I verified that my_other_function is not the cause.

Comment: @Bryan Since he `print_r` after the `my_other_function` call before returning the value, there is no reason for it to change anything.

Comment: @Samsquanch well on the devel/php page when you print out multiple dpm() in the textarea, it shows one dpm() result in a bullet point in the messages region of the page - the bullet point with dpm($new_data) is blank, although there - so technically this is NULL i suppose

Comment: What happens if you do `return array('0' => '12345');` instead of `return $new_data;`?

Comment: @Samsquanch - still doesn't return :(

Comment: @CR47 what happens if you call the other function directly? Do something like `$new_data = my_other_function($data[0]);` and see if you get back something from that. Just to make sure there's not something going on with where you're `dpm()`ing.

Comment: @Samsquanch - that works without issue

Comment: @CR47 what about this: try stripping everything out of your function except the return, and put an array in there like you did above. See if you get a return value then. If so, add in the other pieces one by one until you no longer get a return value. If you don't get a return value with just the return in there, try changing the function name and doing the same thing.

Comment: @Samsquanch - added the original function.

Comment: @CR47 based on the code you posted, I'd say you may be hitting the `reprocess` part of the if statement since that doesn't return anything. Have you made sure you're actually getting into the `else`?

Comment: @Samsquanch - yes i made sure the original data, if it needs to, gets re-processed and the incoming $data on the reprocessing is what it is supposed to be all they way down the line until the return, which is where i dpm($new_data), which looks exactly correct, but will not return

Comment: @CR47 this is going to sound silly, but if you take the return out of the if statement I assume it still doesn't work? (placed after the if)

Comment: @Samsquanch - correct, still does not work

Comment: @CR47 I can safely say that I've exhausted all of my ideas. If you can `dpm()` the data and have what's expected in there, but the return on the very next line isn't actually returning anything... you've got some magical PHP on your hands.

Comment: Uhm... You have two possible exit points at the end. If you're calling `tdm_migration_import_file` recursively again, **you're not returning anything, because the `return` is missing in the `if` branch.**

Comment: @deceze - right, and it goes through that first part of the if statement the first time around, then send the new data back through, which should then result in the else for that last else statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function does not return data here!

```
  ...
  if (isset($new_data['reprocess']) && $new_data['reprocess'] == 'yes') {
    // vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    tdm_migration_import_file($new_data, $inline='no');
    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  } else {
    return $new_data;
  }
```

It doesn't matter that the function calls itself again. It could call *any* function, that's irrelevant. There's no `return` statement here, so the function doesn't return data if it goes into the `if` branch. Fix it:

```
 return tdm_migration_import_file($new_data, $inline='no');
```

Very typical newbie recursive call error.

---

Apparently I need to make more clear *why* this doesn't work as you think. First: **there's nothing special about recursion!.** You're just calling *a* function. It doesn't matter that it's the same function you're currently in. There's no special magic that happens in this case.

Take this example function:

```
function foo() {
    if (rand(0, 1)) {
        bar();
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

This function will only return `true` half the time. The other half, it will call a function `bar` which does who-knows-what, but it will not return any value from that call.

Now substitute `bar()` with `foo()`. It doesn't change anything about the behaviour I described above. The function will still only return data half the time. If there's no `return` statement, it doesn't return data. Plain and simple. Not even from recursive calls.

Calling a function recursively does not "restart" the function, it creates another function call subject to the same rules as any other function call. Your function does not return data if reprocess is equal to yes, period.

Comment: Nice catch. I didn't realize it was a recursive call.

Comment: Doesn't really matter whether it's recursive or not. There's no `return`, hence no return. Plain and simple. :)

Comment: It does matter in this case. If the function wasn't recursive, no return in the `if` part wouldn't matter unless he was expecting a return from that part of the function, which he wouldn't have if it wasn't recursive.

Comment: Not quite sure I'm following your recursive logic. :) The fact that it *is* recursive led the OP to believe it would return data, since it's calling itself after all. Is that what you're saying?

Comment: I'm saying if the function wasn't recursive, not having a return there would have been fine. The reason it is needed is because it is recursive. You said it didn't matter if it was recursive or not, but in the case it most certainly does matter.

Comment: Maybe I'm thinking ahead too far when I'm saying "it doesn't matter". I mean there's obviously no `return`, so the function obviously doesn't return anything. It doesn't matter what function gets called in that `if` branch; no `return` no data. I believe that the OP believes that because the function is calling itself again, it would magically return data from that recursive call even without a `return` statement. And based on that I'm saying that it doesn't matter that the call is recursive, the simple reality is no `return` no data.

Comment: You're right on both accounts. I was just disagreeing with "Doesn't really matter whether it's recursive or not."

Comment: @deceze - I added a step by step description of what the function does to my question so as to explain it better, and why the return not being in the if statement does not matter in this case.

Comment: @Samsquanch - added a step by step description of the function to the question

Comment: If that's the case, then I go back to my answer reverts to "magical PHP".

Comment: @CR47 I added a longer explanation to disprove your step 12 and/or 22.

Comment: @deceze - I must be really confused.  Maybe a second question will help: If the function being called returns data itself, will this work?

Comment: @CR47 No, it will not work. `bar();` does not return data. `return bar();` returns data.

Comment: @CR47 Just literally read aloud what the code does: *If reprocess is true, call [a function], else return data.* Data is only returned in one of two cases here.